# Define an array which the number of rows(clos) is unknown in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, matlab

I have a 2048x2048 matrix of grayscale image,i want to find some points which value are > 0 ,and store its position into an array of 2 columns and n rows (n is also the number of founded points) Here is my algorithm :

```
int icount;
icount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++)
    {
        if (iout.at<double>(i, j) > 0)
        {
            icount++;
            temp[icount][1] = i;
            temp[icount][2] = j;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems :

1. temp is an array which the number of rows is unknown 'cause after each loop the number of rows increases ,so how can i define the temp array ? I need the exact number of rows for another implementation later so i can't give some random number for it.
2. My algorithm above doesn't work,the results is

   ```
   temp[1][1]=0 , temp[1][2]=0 , temp[2][1]=262 , temp[2][2]=655
   ```

   which is completely wrong,the right one is :

   ```
   temp[1][1]=1779 , temp[1][2]=149 , temp[2][1]=1780 , temp[2][2]=149
   ```

   i got the right result because i implemented it in Matlab, it is

   ```
   [a,b]=find(iout>0);
   ```

Comment: If you don't know the size of an array, then use [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: How did you define & initialize temp? I suspect you get odd results because you're addressing illegal memeory

Comment: if vector or other dynamic structures dont fit your needs you can loop the whole image twice. first count. second create mat/array of needed size and insert all elements.

Comment: @Amit can you be more specified ? i'm new to C++ and my knowledge about it is very limit . I tried another define such as : 

`int **temp`  and my program broke :

 " A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DoAnTinHoc.exe An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DoAnTinHoc.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 


@Micka i did as you suggest and it's still broke because of "Stackoverflow Exception" . it sometimes count up to 1500000 points

Comment: I added an answer to explain how to work with `int **temp`, but I must say I don't think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/):

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> temp;
```

Then add `(i, j)` pairs to it using `push_back`. No size needed to be known in advance:

```
temp.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
```

We'll need to know more about your problem and your code to be able to tell what's wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: even better, `push_back({ i, j })` or `emplace_back(i, j)` for readability.

Comment: i was wrong about the result,i forgot about the row-column order rule between Matlab and C++. But still,i can't find a way to store those positions. I tried your code,but when i put it in the loop like this : 
`for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++)
  {
   if (iout.at<double>(i,j) > 0)
   {
    icount++;
    temp.push_back(make_pair(icount,1)) = i;
    temp.push_back(make_pair(icount,2)) = j;
   }
  }
 }`
and the compiler say this : "IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue" . i have no idea

Comment: @PhạmXuânHiển that's not how you do it. you just do `temp.push_back(make_pair(i, j));`. Nothing more. You can then use `temp.size()` to get the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable of pointer type, you need to allocate memory and have the pointer point to that memory address. In your case, you have a multidimensional pointer so it requires multiple allocations. For example:

```
int **temp = new int *[100]; // This means you have room for 100 arrays (in the 2nd dimension)
int icount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 2048; j++) {
      if(iout.at<double>(i, j) > 0) {
         temp[icount] = new int[2]; // only 2 variables needed at this dimension
         temp[icount][1] = i;
         temp[icount][2] = j;
         icount++;
      }
   }
}
```

This will work for you, but it's only good if you know for sure you're not going to need any more than the pre-allocated array size (100 in this example). If you know exactly how much you need, this method is ok. If you know the maximum possible, it's also ok, but could be wasteful. If you have no idea what size you need in the first dimension, you have to use a dynamic collection, for example `std::vector` as suggested by IVlad. In case you do use the method I suggested, don't forget to free the allocated memory using `delete []temp[i];` and `delete []temp;`